# snmp agent using OpenDMK

Tags: snmp4j, oid, opendmk

I am trying to code an Snmp agent using OpenDMK but the project is not able to build while using 'ant buildall' command in command prompt.

I have followed the same steps as written over here "https://opendmk.java.net/download/index.html". But in the end it shows "BUILD FAIL" with 100 errors and 100 warnings. I want to use mibgen and I can't find another way.

Also plz let me know if there is any way to do this using snmp4j-agent. There I am getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LOCAL_ENGINE_ID

I want to register OIDs with snmp agent and want to integrate the same with manager server. Also I am working on Windows 7 with jdk 1.8

Answer (score 0):

"Maybe" it's too late but you don't need to build the project to use the mibgen command from OpenDMK.

I've just downloaded the Full Binary Bundle from the page that you pointed and it contains that command ready to use. I can generate the MBean interfaces and implementations from a MIB file.

I only have to change the file mibgen.bat to point **JDMK_HOME** to my distribution.